# AngularJS ng-bind to specific array element

Tags: angularjs

I have elements in my page that's being repeated as rendered by ASP.Net MVC. (I need to do this for SEO purposes.)

Within these elements, I would like to have a text field that's bound by AngularJS.

Is there a way to do this?

In the code below, for example, the 2nd and 3rd text fields don't even allow me to type anything. Is it because I have not properly initialized the array or is there something wrong with the syntax?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />
<input type="text" ng-model="sometextArray1[1]" />
<input type="text" ng-model="sometextArray2[1].value" />


<h1>Hello #1 {{ sometext }}</h1>
<h1>Hello #2 {{ sometextArray1[1] }}</h1>
<h1>Hello #3 {{ sometextArray2[1].value }}</h1>
```

Comment: sometext is a string. sometextArray1 and sometextArray2 are arrays of strings. I just added the first one for me to validate that AngularJS and two-way binding works.

Comment: This sounds like a case for a directive, where you would transclude the contents of each item, and you would have a scope available to each. You would then aggregate each into a parent directive in the link function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to let angular implicitly instantiate the array for you, I don't think arrays are assignable. If you are using a controller to instantiate your array this should work. I have created a fiddle.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysw484ec/)

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="mod">  
    <section ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="someArray[0].value" ng-change="logValue(0)" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="someArray[1].value" ng-change="logValue(1)"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="someArray[2].value" ng-change="logValue(2)"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="someArray[3].value" ng-change="logValue(3)"/>
    </section>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('mod', []);

    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log) {
        $scope.someArray = [
            {value: "value 0"}, 
            {value: "value 1"},
            {value: "value 2"}, 
            {value: "value 3"}
        ];

        $scope.logValue = function (index) {
            $log.info($scope.someArray[index]);
        }
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: Indexers are assignable as far as I know (but I haven't tested either).

Comment: I'm not iterating using Angular. I have repeated elements that were rendered from the server that's going to be like rows of input fields that go: sometextArray[1]... sometextArray[2] and so on. Are you suggesting I create repeated instances of a controller in this case? Can I instantiate an array of controllers in Angular?

Comment: Thanks. This worked. All I needed to do was to initialize the array properly. I originally set it as an array of string. What worked was to set it as an array of objects with a string property.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you like my answer an up vote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a directive to your list and another for each item using isolate scope.

> **Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yZyxzACNtXEA661sy0K3?p=preview)**

you will get all the content of your items by transcluding them into a directive template

```
transclude: true,
//
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

You can add to your isolate scope per item from the attribute like you just need a way to index each scope like `scope="scope1"` | `scope="scope2"`

```
<list-item name="First Item" scope="scope1" func="func1(scope)">
```

In your directive you use operators like - **@** String, **=** Model, **&** Function

```
// Directive
scope: {
  'name': '@',
  'iscope': '=scope',
  'func': '&'
}
```

Then in the container controller you can create the a sort of indexed array of item scopes like you would with an ng-repeat.

```
$scope.addItem = function(scope) {
   $scope.items.push(scope);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried this solution yet but I'll look at it sometime. I chose the other answer because I got it to work without requiring major changes to my existing code.